# Set multiple options in an array and make them accessible in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, associative-array

I want to create some variables / options to customize my wordpress theme.

At the moment I already have 5 variables which I set inside the `functions.php` file:

```
$isBoxedLayout = true;
$postCounter = 0;
$postDate = false;
$socialButtons;
$showCatLink = false;
```

I access them throughout the other files like `header.php`, `content.php` etc.:

```
global $isBoxedLayout;
global $postCounter;
```

At the top of the files. I think it would be better to have like only one array where I can store it all!? But how do I do it right?

Also, does somebody know how I can access a variable, set in the `functions.php`, inside the `template-tags.php` file?

I already tried this:

```
include '../functions.php'
```

But I get the following error:

```
include(../functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

When I want to access the variable in a file like `content.php` it works well. Where is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not exactly the answer you are looking for, but I would take a look at the [Options API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API). It saves your options into the database and is very easy to use.

```
// Functions.php
add_option( 'isBoxedLayout', true, '', 'yes' );


// template-tags.php
$isBoxedLayout = get_option( 'isBoxedLayout' );
```